# Negative numbers are not recognized

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Prints "Hello, World" in the terminal window.

      Scanner quest = new Scanner(System.in);enter code here
      System.out.println("How old are you?: ");
      int num = quest.nextInt();

      if (num <= 12){
        System.out.println("You are too young to be on the computer!!!!");
      } else if (num >=13 && num <= 17){
        System.out.println("Welcome young teen");
      } else if (17 < num && num <= 60){
        System.out.println("Welcome adult");
      } else if (60 < num){
        System.out.println("Welcome senior citizen!!");
      } else{
        System.out.println("Invalid age.");
      }

   }
}
```

When I enter a negative number it just falls under the "You are too young to be on the computer!!!!" instead of displaying "Invalid age." I have tried changing the condition but it id not seem to work.

Comment: That's because it's the first condition. Do `num <= 12 && num > 0` or something.

Comment: Negative value makes the first `if` true, and then that what it displays.

Comment: Damn that new fangled maths where -1 > 12 !

Comment: What the peanut gallery above are trying to say is `if (num <= 12)` should be `if (num > 0 && <= 12)`

Comment: That's because a negative number is less than 12.

Answer (score 1):

Because a negative number is less than 12, you *could* simplify your chain of `if-else` blocks by testing for negative values and eliminating your `&&` checks by relying on the previously checked conditions. Like,

```
int num = quest.nextInt();
if (num < 0) { // <-- negative values.
    System.out.println("Invalid age.");
} else if (num <= 12) { // <-- (0, 12)
    System.out.println("You are too young to be on the computer!!!!");
} else if (num <= 17) { // <-- (13, 17)
    System.out.println("Welcome young teen");
} else if (num <= 60) { // <-- (18, 60)
    System.out.println("Welcome adult");
} else { // <-- greater than 60
    System.out.println("Welcome senior citizen!!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have made it your first condition with the `if(Condition) { //Code }` statement. Well I did a run on the code and kinda make a little adjustment to your code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Prints "Hello, World" in the terminal window.

      Scanner quest = new Scanner(System.in); //enter code here
      System.out.println("How old are you?: ");
      int num = quest.nextInt();

      if (num <= 0) {
          System.out.println("Invalid age.");
      } else if (num <= 12){
        System.out.println("You are too young to be on the computer!!!!");
      } else if (num >=13 && num <= 17){
        System.out.println("Welcome young teen");
      } else if (17 < num && num <= 60){
        System.out.println("Welcome adult");
      } else if (60 < num){
        System.out.println("Welcome senior citizen!!");
      } 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you both guys, really helped. Also helped my simplify my code a lot. Its been a while since I have coded so my logic still isn't there.

Comment: If my answer or any other user answer was of use to solve your problem(s) kindly mark it as answered and upvote it @GabeGomez